# Get address from latitude and longitude in ios

Tags: ios, mkmapview, core-location

I have been programming for ios and I need to get address.
How can I get full address from latitude and longitude in json or other format? Can I get it without internet connection?
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is the [`CLGeocoder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder) (on iOS 5) and [`MKReverseGeocoder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008323) (on older iOS versions).

Both use Google Maps to get address data so you need an internet connection to get data.

You'll get address as `NSDictionary`, but you can easily convert it to a JSON string with [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) or many other tools.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the Apple documentation for CLGeocoder -- specifically the reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: method.  It takes a CLLocation and returns reverse Geocode information you're looking for.  And since this uses Google Maps, you will need an Internet connection.

Comment: Why did you posted quite the same answer?

Answer (score -1):

You should check out [Reverse GeoCoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This is depreciated as of iOS 5.0